# Enabling mysql Event scheduler on server restarts

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, scheduling

I am running phpmyadmin and installed apache server on my personal computer. My problem is that I am trying to set MySQL `event_scheduler` to always be enabled even when the server restarts. I was reading that by setting the following command line in the server configuration file (`my.cnf` or `my.ini`) it should work: `event_scheduler=DISABLED`. However, where do I locate this `my.cnf` or `my.ini` file, and also should the command line be `event_scheduler=DISABLED` or `event_scheduler=ENABLED` seeing that I want it to always be enabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set 'ON' value (not ENABLED).

In the configuration file in [mysqld] section specify 'event-scheduler' option (not event_scheduler).

Also, you can start your MySQL server with '--event-scheduler' option, e.g. -

shell> mysqld --event-scheduler=ON

More information - [event_scheduler system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler).

Comment: Could you take a look at this question please I really need some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088948/mysql-event-running-yearly-calculations

Comment: Add event_scheduler=ON  in your /etc/my.cnf file, in [mysqld] section. (Yes, it's "event_scheduler", not "event-scheduler" :D )   Read more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html#events-event-scheduler-option

Answer (score 7):

Add to my.cnf file to [mysqld] section.

```
GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON
```

Restart your mysql server. Check status with this command :

```
mysql> select @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler;
+--------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.event_scheduler |
+--------------------------+
| ON                       |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'event_scheduler';
+-----------------+-------+
| Variable_name   | Value |
+-----------------+-------+
| event_scheduler | ON    |
+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here the path for `my.ini` on XAMPP:

```
xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
```

Open `my.ini`  and add the following

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler=ON
```

then restart MySQL service.

To check the status use the below MySQL query:

```
SELECT @@event_scheduler
```

Comment: @Cleb Kumar  how about in live server sir ?

Answer (score 3):

For [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com):

1. Edit your my.ini file and under the [mysqld] section, add this:

   `event-scheduler=on`
2. restart all services
3. verify by running this query:

   `select @@event_scheduler`;

To get to your my.ini file, just click the WAMP tray icon and hover over the 'MySQL' menu, and click 'my.ini'.

Answer (score 0):

FOR [MAMP](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2010/02/how-to-set-mysql-default-storage-engine.html) on OS X:

the default installation does not include a `my.cnf` file so you need to create one and set up your default configuration.  Therefore, to enable the the scheduler on an OS X MAMP stack, you need to,

1. stop your MySQL server
2. create a `my.cnf` file in your `/Applications/MAMP/conf/` folder, you will need root access to do this (open a terminal window),

   > sudo touch /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf
   >
   > sudo nano /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf
3. the 2nd cmd will open the nano editor, paste the following in your file,

   > [mysqld]
   >
   > event_scheduler=ON
4. Save (`^O`) and exit (`^X`) the nano editor
5. restart your MySQL server.