# MySQL Recurring event stops working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a reccurring event that should occur every day and with no end date. So I went with:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`xxx` EVENT `my_event` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2016-08-23 08:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO TRUNCATE TABLE `my_table`
```

Now, my issue is that the event seems to stop working after a while. Maybe after a reboot? What could do this? The mysql `error.log` is empty. How can I debug this ?

And by the way, am I right to select `preserve on completion`?

**EDIT**
Ok, I think that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071871/enabling-mysql-event-scheduler-on-server-restarts) the solution to my problem. So I guess that I should put the line

```
event_scheduler=ON
```

at the bottom of the `[mysqld]` section of the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

I just need to restart to be sure, but I can't do that right now.

Comment: what does this get you: `show variables where variable_name='event_scheduler';`  ... and yes preserve

Comment: Well... Event_scheduler : OFF. This means that it is getting disabled. Might it be during reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071871/enabling-mysql-event-scheduler-on-server-restarts) the solution to my problem.

The version in this link is not the same as mine. With the current version it seems that I have to put

```
event_scheduler=ON
```

at the bottom of the [mysqld] section of the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

After reboot, it is working.